# Using a system command with parameter from program in C++

Tags: c++

So I'm doing a project for school and was trying to use the windows function "mkdir", but the directory name would be a string given by the program. Here's the (not very useful) code:

```
string c,a;
cin>>c;
if(c.compare("mkdir")==0)
    cin>>a;
    system("mkdir"); //here I want to make the directory
}
```

Comment: They're [simpler ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx) to create directories...

Comment: On which operating system? I am surprised you are given this homework on Windows (however, coding a shell on Linux is a very common homework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directories don't exist for the C++11 (or C++14) standard. Later C++ standard (e.g. C++17 ...) might offer the [std::filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library.

You could use operating system specific primitives. On Linux and POSIX, consider the [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) system call (and [CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx) function on Windows).

You could find framework libraries (e.g. [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/), [Boost](http://boost.org/), ....) wrapping these, so with these libraries you won't care about OS specific functions.

> but the directory name would be a string given by the program.

Then you could consider building a command as a runtime C string for [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). E.g. with [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) (or with some `std::string` operation). Beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) (e.g. think of the malicious user providing `/tmp/foo; rm -rf $HOME` as his directory name on Linux)!

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, it would be better to create the directory without using the `system` call. If you would like to use that method regardless, you need to [build a command string which includes your arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540243/system-function-in-c-is-not-working-for-me) prior to passing it to `system`.

```
char command[100];
sprintf(command, "mkdir %s", a);
system(command);
```

Comment: I recommend using `snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "mkdir %s", a);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want create folder use WinApi see [CreateFolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235679/create-a-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of:

```
string c;
cin >> c;
if(c == "mkdir") {
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    system("mkdir " + a);
}
```

But if this project involves writing some kind of command shell, `system` is very likely off-limits and you're expected to use the operating system's API directly.